# Neo4jClient/Cypher query returns object but without setting properties

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I just can't get an object out of Neo4j through Neo4jClient and Cypher.

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://mymachine:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
var myList = client.RootNode.StartCypher("root")
    .Match("root-[:RELATED_TO]->(user)")
    .Return<User>("user").Results;
```

I get a User object in myList[0] alright but its properties are empty.

I get the same (object with empty properties) through

```
client.ExecuteGetCypherResults<User>(
    new CypherQuery("start n=node(1) return n;",null, CypherResultMode.Set)
);
```

What obvious thing have I overlooked?

(Neo4j 1.8 MS5, Neo4jClient 1.0.0.388)

/Neo4jClient/Neo4j noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay!  I changed to Node like so:

```
var myList = client.RootNode.StartCypher("root")
    .Match("root-[:RELATED_TO]->(user)")
    .Return<Node<User>>("user").Results;
```

and finally

```
var myList = client.RootNode.StartCypher("root")
    .Match("root-[:RELATED_TO]->(user)")
    .Return<Node<User>>("user").Results
    .Select( nu => nu.Data );
```

The simplest example should be:

```
var myList = client.ExecuteGetCypherResults<Node<User>>(
    new CypherQuery("start n=node(1) return n;", null, CypherResultMode.Set))
.Select(un => un.Data);
```

where 1 is the ID of the User node.

Comment: Googling the same question a year later I found another Culprit. The fields of the User class must be public. Internal is not enough.

Comment: Instead of using Return<Node<User>>, then throwing it away with the Select call, just use Return<User>.